# How to calculate the operator norm of $f\mapsto (Af)(x) = xf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have to solve the following exercise:

"Consider the vector space $X = C[0, 1]$ of the continuous functions $f : x \rightarrow f(x)$ over the interval $[0, 1]$ and the norm $$\|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|.$$
Consider the operator on $X$ defined as $(Af)(x) = xf(x)$. Show that it is bounded and compute its norm."

Now to show that $A$ is bounded, is it legitimate to say that since $X$ is the space of continuous functions, also $A$ is a continuous operator and hence bounded?

Also, I know the definition of the operator norm, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it.

Comment: Can you state what definition of operator norm you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Let f such that $\|f\|=1$ then, 
$$\|Af\|= \sup_{[0,1]}|xf(x)|\le \sup_{[0,1]}|f(x)| =\|f\|=1$$

Hence, $$\|A\| =\sup_{\|f\| =1}\|Af\| \le 1$$

Taking,  $f_0(x)= 1$ we have, $Af_0(x) =x$ and $$\color{red}{1\ge \|A\|\ge \|Af_0\| = \sup_{[0,1]}|x| =1}$$

> Therefore, 
>   $$\|A\| =\sup_{\|f\| =1}\|Af\| =1$$

Answer (score 2):

> Now to show that $A$ is bounded, is it legitimate to say that since $X$ is the space of continuous functions, also $A$ is a continuous operator and hence bounded?

No, that would be begging the question. Just because it's an operator on a space of continuous functions, does not *per se* mean it is continuous. For linear operators on Banach space, continuity and boundedness are equivalent. So assuming continuity is assuming what you are meant to prove.

(Although in contemporary colloquial usage, the phrase "begging the question" has come to mean "raises a good question", in rhetoric and logic, it means something quite different. It means the fallacy of arguing by assuming what you are meant to prove.)

---

So how *do* we show that $A$ is bounded? We need to find an $M$ such that for all $f\in C[0,1],$ we have $\lVert Af\rVert\leq M\lVert f\rVert.$ An $M$ such that for all $f$ $\sup \lvert xf(x)\rvert\leq M\sup\lvert f(x)\rvert.$ Can you think of an $M$ that will work? Hint: since $0\leq x\leq 1,$ $xf(x)$ doesn't take any larger values than $f(x).$

Comment: To give en example, the derivative is a linear operator which is unbounded for \(C[0,1]\)

Comment: @TonyS.F. have to be careful how we say it. the derivative operator is not defined on $C[0,1]$. And on any closed subspace where it is defined, any linear operator is also bounded. But yes, the differentiable functions are a subspace in $C[0,1]$ which is not closed, and the derivative is not bounded on this subspace.

Comment: Yeah you're right that was careless of me.